# Most question tagged with [photoshop] are closed

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

Am I wrong or are most of the question tagged with [photoshop](/questions/tagged/photoshop) closed?

Since Photoshop is a program that is used to generate/manipulate/edit images, people will actually ask question about how to do things with images.

So you can't close the question if it's not related to programming.

I think the solution will be to delete the [photoshop](/questions/tagged/photoshop) tag so people won't use it wrongly and get their questions closed, or retag it to [photoshop-scripting](/questions/tagged/photoshop-scripting) or something like that.

Comment: Y'know... There's a [tag:java] tag too, but questions about coffee *and* Indonesian culture are off-topic. It's just one of those things.

Comment: renaming tags to define them more not such a big deal

Comment: @AlmoullimDev. Alright, so propose a tag name for photoshop that doesn't limit the range of programming questions that can be asked with it. As I mentioned, [photoshop-scripting] is too restrictive.

Comment: @Manishearth probable it will be rejected so ... why will i try,  looks like people dont realy agree with so , **no need for that**

Comment: +1 to more specific tags in this case.

Answer (score 6):

If we followed that reasoning everywhere, [facebook](/questions/tagged/facebook) would have been destroyed a while ago.

As long as there is a programming-related aspect to a concept, and it's not a meta-tag, a tag can exist here just fine even if a lot of questions within it are closed. If there is a programming-related question about Photoshop, it's fine here. If the question has nothing to do with programming, we will close it as usual.

Comment: dont destroye the tag but rename it to [tag:facebook-scripting] !!

Comment: Destroy the `facebook` tag you say?  Wait... which side are we on again?

Comment: @BilltheLizard what are talking about exactly ?

Comment: Yes, destroy Facebook. It is an _evil scourge upon this earth_.

Answer (score 4):

No, just because a tag exists doesn't mean that all questions on that topic are allowed. You still have to follow the site scope, which is about *programming questions*.

Questions on the usage of photoshop *might* be OK on [Super User](http://superuser.com), though.

You may want to see [this list](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5Bphotoshop%5D%20closed:0) to get an idea of hat a good Photoshop question on SO is like.

Comment: well then rename it with a programing name

Comment: @AlmoullimDev. Not all [photoshop] questions are about scripting. See the list. I repeat, the existence of a tag does nothing to make question on that topic allowed.

Comment: @AlmoullimDev. When you come to this site it is understood that you are here for a programming question. There is no need to clarify that in the tags.

Comment: @Manishearth i thinks that renaming the tag will reduce the closed questions

Comment: @NickieZahra by 20%

Comment: @AlmoullimDev. I'm curious as to the study you conducted to come to that conclusion.  If you're going to give numbers, the least I expect is what they are based off of.

Comment: @Daedalus nickie said i thinks that renaming the tag will reduce the closed questions , i siad will be reduced by 20%

Comment: @AlmoullimDev. I'm asking how you came to the conclusion it will be reduced by 20%.

Comment: @Daedalus because that people will more understand what the tag means ( that is a Photoshop script ) and wont used it to start questions that not related with this , so question that off-topic will be less so you can calc how many people who only read the tag and post under it, get the number and and remove these people post and the reduced closed and deleted questions will be much like 20% because most of people are a bit lazy and dont like to read too much stuff so i manged to get the % to %20 ... correct me if im wrong

Comment: @AlmoullimDev. From what you say, it appears you don't actually have any hard numbers or math going on here, so I'm going to bow out of this due to SOM's rules on discussions, as nothing constructive is going to come of this.

Comment: @Daedalus While it is obvious that this discussion is going nowhere (and bowing out makes sense), what rules? AFAICT, MSO allows discussion without much restriction.

Comment: @Manishearth [Under the shouldn't header](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); secondary discussions, specifically.

Comment: @Daedalus Hmm, right. Except that that's the main site privilege page (the privilege wikis on Meta are transcluded on all other sites). Meta is _for_ discussion, though yeah, off topic threads are liable to get deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a look, it seems that most photoshop tagged questions are actually not closed (is there a way to find out exactly how many are closed?) - many are open, some are downvoted for reasons described by Brad Larson and Manishearth.

It is not that hard to try several things, research more techniques - adapt and try them, then post a question with the results of the work done and ask a specific question about the programming that you have tried.

Comment: many open so is many closed **i dont see how this helps for my question !!!!**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphotoshop%5D+closed%3A1 - 238 out of 992, or roughly 24%. Of course, there are also a lot of closed and deleted questions, making the real % something like 40%.

Comment: @Shog9 thank you for that - there is still a majority open.

Comment: @Shog9 will `%40` from `%100` its not a small number you know ...